# How to create Azure AD user programmatically?

Tags: c#, azure, azure-active-directory

I understand there is azure portal to manage groups, user and etc.

Are there any ways to do it programmatically (either using web-api or sdk in C#)?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 16):

It is easy to create Azure AD users using the Microsoft Graph REST. Here is a code sample for your reference:

```
POST https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users 
Authorization: Bearer {token}
Content-type: application/json

{
  "accountEnabled": true,
  "displayName": "displayName-value",
  "mailNickname": "mailNickname-value",
  "userPrincipalName": "upn-value@tenant-value.onmicrosoft.com",
  "passwordProfile" : {
    "forceChangePasswordNextSignIn": true,
    "password": "password-value"
  }
}
```

It also provides the corresponding library using C# from [here](https://github.com/microsoftgraph/msgraph-sdk-dotnet). More detail about Microsoft Graph, you can refer the link below:

[Overview of Microsoft Graph](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/concepts/overview)

[Get access tokens to call Microsoft Graph](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/concepts/auth_overview)

[Create User](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/api-reference/v1.0/api/user_post_users)

Comment: I am working on an web app and using dotnet core webapi on the backend. I have a UsersController and want to use the endpoints on that controller to get info about my users in AzureAD. Endpoint is `/api/users?id={id}` How can I redirect the request to `https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users` ? Is token in Authorization: Bearer {token} the token of the currently logged in user? Or is it a more general token for my app? My web app is also hosted in Azure. Do I need to add Microsoft Graph to it?

Comment: If you only want to get the specific user info of current user sign-in, you can get the delegate token for user. What did you mean redirect the request? For get the user info of current user, you can refer [active-directory-dotnet-graphapi-web](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-dotnet-graphapi-web).

Comment: If I needed to manage multiple groups and users in the context of user management, and I want to create a web application for this purpose, I want a delegated admin type user/group who can log into the application and administer. Regular users can only login and view their profile and perhaps update their password. Should I use a service principal (not fully familiar with the concept) or assign Global administrator rights to these admin users? The purpose of this is for user authentication in another application that relies on this tenant to get oauth2 tokens.

Comment: @kanpeki the Bearer token should be the token of the user who is trying to add new user if that makes sense.

Comment: Can I also use Microsoft Graph REST in Azure AD B2C?

Answer (score 11):

Using C# and the Graph API library Fei Xue mentioned, you can write code like this:

```
User newUser = new User
{
    Id = user.Id,
    BusinessPhones = someUser.BusinessPhones,
    DisplayName = someUser.DisplayName,
    GivenName = someUser.GivenName,
    JobTitle = someUser.JobTitle,
    Mail = someUser.Mail,
    MobilePhone = someUser.MobilePhone,
    OfficeLocation = someUser.OfficeLocation,
    PreferredLanguage = someUser.PreferredLanguage,
    Surname = someUser.Surname,
    UserPrincipalName = someUser.UserPrincipalName
};
User createdUser = await graphClient.Users.Request().AddAsync(newUser);
```

User is a class provided by the Graph package. The graphClient object is a GraphServiceClient object which provides the connection and authentication information.

Also, there is a core set of User information that is supported. You can see them in the response to the [Create User](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/user-post-users) example in the User documentation. There are other properties listed in the docs for User, but these "belong" to applications like SharePoint, Office 365, etc. and are not available without a license to that application.

Note the documentation is sparse, so it is sometimes trial and error to get something working.

I've been using the [Graph Snippets example](https://github.com/microsoftgraph/aspnet-snippets-sample) to gain experience with this. It has lots of usage examples. Another great resource is the Graph Explorer which lets you try things real time.

If you're having trouble, I've been told that the Azure and Graph developers monitor SO and respond pretty quickly to questions.That's been my experience so far.

Good luck!