# Use AzureAD for Users that have known Email and Mobile number but not an Account in AzureAD

Tags: azure-active-directory

We are building a System that receives Message that a User like to View. With each Message we receive also the EMail and Mobile number.

As to build a save Login is tricky, we like to use AzureAD (our App will run in the Azure Cloud).

I think the flow has to look like that:

1. The backend calls azure AD to create the user or some kind of user with email + mobile number.
2. The User receive a Mail with a link to our app. Then the gets redirected to the login. There he must validate the EMail + Mobile number.
3. Than he is logged in.

Is this possible? Or there other better ways?

Best regards G

Answer (score 0):

1. User performs a registration with the follwing info: name, email, mobile number
2. Backend app creates the user in AAD using Graph API:
   [How to create Azure AD user programmatically?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44756742/how-to-create-azure-ad-user-programmatically?msclkid=3065f195aad711ecb22215e42c6b0b87)

The AAD user profile can hold the name, email and number
(does not have to be an Exchange address).

3. Backend app sends an email to the customer with the username, temp password and login link
4. Customer clicks on link, signs in, and is forced to change password. This validates email address.  Validate the mobile number and then registration is complete.
5. At this time, anytime user logs in, the application just works.